# How to support a two-way lookup in dynamodb while ensuring uniqueness?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've to map two distinct set of unique ids. Example:

| ID | Ext ID |
| --- | --- |
| 130540d9-33bb-40a4-aab1-e753c78eee5d | movieprovider1#00001 |
| ed4487b7-1487-4a10-9397-29c5c5eedf60 | movieprovider2#00001 |

Now need to ensure that everything in the ID column is unique, and everything in the Ext ID column. I also need fast lookup based on ID and Ext ID.
If I make ID my parition key it's solved for ID. But Ext ID is an issue. Global Secondary Index do not enforce uniqueness, so no solution for Ext ID.

How can I ensure that ID and Ext ID remains unique while still providing fast lookup on both? A dummy entry for id and always maintain two entries upon insert and delete?

Comment: Read [Simulating Amazon DynamoDB unique constraints using transactions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/simulating-amazon-dynamodb-unique-constraints-using-transactions/).

Comment: @jarmod Nothing new since 2019? Some inbuild way so forgetting the second entry while deleting doesn't happen? This feels like such a common requirement, just the partition key being uniquely restrained seems rare'ish

Comment: Alternatively, use a form of Single Table Design where your PK is id#130540d9-33bb-40a4-aab1-e753c78eee5d for one item and exitd#movieprovider1#00001 for the related Ext ID, and do both inserts in a transaction, with attribute_not_exists conditions. But if you want an RDBMS, and it suits your scalability needs and access patterns, then use an RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

If you would want to ensure there's only ever one unique value for both the ID and ExtId, one option could be using conditonal writes when you perform Put or UpdateItem operations.

You could specify the attribute_not_exists(ExtId) as your condition and it would reject any update/create of an item, if there's already an item with the same attribute value you specify as ExtId.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html

But, just verifying it wouldn't suffice to you if you just defined your table with composite primary key, leveraging ID as partition and ExtId as sort key? It leaves the possibility though that you could have the same extid on multiple partitions, but  in that case you could use the same conditional writes to cover them.

Comment: Conditional write would mean a full table scan for the attribute every time though. Additionally if two condidional writes happen in parallel both would succeed if I am not mistaken?

Comment: @Regyn A conditional put using attribute_not_exists does not scan the table. This is an efficient way to ensure you don't overwrite an item with the same PK value.

Comment: @jarmod But attribute_not_exists(ExtId) is performed on ExtId, which isn't a PK.

Comment: That's not a viable option for SK uniqueness checking. You need to invoke attribute_not_exists on a PK, and that's why the page I pointed you to advises a solution where secondary key constraints, such as Ext ID in your case, are actually PKs on another table (and that's where the attribute_not_exists  executes, within a transaction).

Answer (score 0):

You can write two items using transactions, one as ID/ExtID and the other ExtID/ID. Name your attributes as PK and SK so there’s no assumption of what ID either is because it’s going to vary.

Make each write conditional on the item not already existing. If either write fails the other is failed as well.

If there’s a chance of an ID and ExtID having the same value then prepend ID# or ExtID# depending, to disambiguate.